# Change Appendix pagestyle from fancy style

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\rightmark}}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\include {1.Introduction}
\include {2.Background}
\include {3.Literature}
\include {4.Methodology}
\include{5.ExperimentalAnalysis}
\include{6.CaseStudy}
\include{7.Conclusion}
\include{Appendix}
```

The above code has done the following style in all chapters including the appendices. However, I want the fancy style in all the chapters except in the appendix chapter.
[image: The fancy style should not appear in the appendix, but in other chapters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the effect of `\pagestyle` in a group:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\rightmark}}}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\pagestyle{fancy}
\Blinddocument
\clearpage
\egroup

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage{changepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\ChNameVar{\centering\Large\rm\bfseries}
\ChNumVar{\Huge}
\ChTitleVar{\centering\Huge\rm\bfseries}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase
\ChRuleWidth{1pt}
The above code has done the style in all chapters including the appendices. However, I want the fancychap style in all the chapters except in the appendix chapter.

Comment: Does your comment mean, that my answer doesn't answer your question? In that case, could you please elaborate? Or is this a new question with new code? Then you might ask a new question in a new thread.